# Repair crack between wall and ceiling

Tags: ceiling, caulking, crack, spray-foam

[image: crack]

I have a crack where the ceiling meets the wall. The ceiling is drywall and the wall is wood (log). At its widest point (on the right) the crack is 1" wide and it tapers to the left and runs for 24". (Only the right 12" is visible in the image.)

In searching DIY I was surprised that this hadn't already been asked (in this type of detail) and answered - or I failed in searching.

My question is "How do I repair this?" and this can further be broken down into (1) materials and (2) technique.

First off, I've never done this before so really don't know what I'm doing.

In researching materials I've come across acrylic sealants, caulking sealants and expanding foams but not sure which is most appropriate.

For technique, I'm sure that whatever I use is going to be paste or liquid-like and is going to drip as soon as I insert it so how do I stop that from happening? Do I insert and then quickly put masking tape over?

EDIT: Zoom out image as requested.

[image: zoom out]

Comment: Kind of big for sealants alone.  Almost looks like someone made a boo-boo in measurements.  Should edit your question with how good you want the finish to be and add a picture of larger area.  It is a good close up picture but hard to tell what we are looking at.

Comment: First thing you need to do is to provide a backer in the wide part of the gap so that whatever you chose to finish off the gap has something to hold onto.  After that, I would maybe use some backer rod, joint compound, and tape to finish it off.

Comment: @crip659 - I added a zoom out image. "how good finish?" - it's more important for it to be a good solid seal that pretty/aesthetic.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was set up for molding. There are many nice moldings that will do the job, just visit your favorite box store. They come in finished, and ready to stain Hardwood, softwood and plastic. If you want to get fancy you can put the molding a bit below the ceiling and place LED lighting in it, it would make the ceiling sort of glow. On the sides you could also use a similar molding or even quarter round.